# React native: passing image path as params through 2 components

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

i'm trying to pass an image path down to one component via react-navigation params and from that component to a third one as a prop.

This is a chat application and the structure of the components is:

ChatsMain.js --> (click on SingleChat, passing parameters when navigating) --> SingleConversation.js  --> Message

I can pass 'name' as a parameter, but not the uri of an image, not even by assigning it to variables.

The name that i see on the SingleChat is passed without problems to the correspondent conversation, but when i pass the image i get the error:
'Failed prop type: Invalid prop `source` supplied to `Image`.'

I hope it's clear enough, i don't think it's the correct way to do this, but i am new to react native!

ChatsMain.js

```
const imageNames = {
    juf: require('../assets/juf.png'),
    meester: require('../assets/meester.png'),
    groep: require('../assets/groep.png'),
    onderwerpen: require('../assets/onderwerpen.png')
}

export default class ChatsMain extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (

                        <SingleChat
                            image={imageNames.juf}
                            backgroundColor={yellow}
                            borderColor={blue}
                            name='Juf Elsa'
                            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SingleConversation', {name: 'Juf Elsa', image: imageNames.juf})}
                        />
)
```

SingleConversation.js

```
export default class SingleConversation extends React.Component {

    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
        return {
            title: navigation.getParam('name', 'Chat'),
            headerStyle: [titleBar, { backgroundColor: yellow }],
            headerTitleStyle: [title, { color: blue }]
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={chatMainContainer}>
                    <ScrollView style={chatsContent}>
                        <Message image={({navigation}) => navigation.getParam('image', 'image')} />
                    </ScrollView>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Message.js

```
export default class ReceivedFirst extends React.Component {

    render(
        ){
        return(
            <View style={textWithPicture}>
            <View style={[chatPhotoContainer, { borderColor: yellow }]}>
                <Image source={this.props.image} style={{ width: 70, height: 70}} />
.....
.....
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this.props.navigation.state.params` instead `this.props.navigation.getParam`

```js
export default class SingleConversation extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      image: this.props.navigation.state.params.image
    };
  }
...
Message image={this.state.image} />
```

OR 
You need to get a Navigation from the props.

```js
    render() {
     const { navigation } = this.props
        return (
            <View style={chatMainContainer}>
                    <ScrollView style={chatsContent}>
                        <Message image={() => navigation.getParam('image', 'image')} />
                    </ScrollView>
            </View>
        );
    }
```

Comment: @AlbaFerrari  If my answer was helpful, would you please select the 'V' sign and arrow for my answer?

Comment: I tried but got this message:
"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."